# Network manager doesn't remember login (username)

Tags: login, network-manager, vpn

I'm using network-manager to connect to VPN. I fill the username and password and check to remember password. But when I'm trying to connect next time it does not remember the username - only username, password is prefilled. It's quite annoying and unfortunately I have no idea how to fix...

Thanks for answers.

(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Which VPN type?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the correct answer to your question. What type do you mean? I'm using it instead of the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using openconnect, with the corresponding NetworkManager plugin.

Sounds like https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332491

It's a bug in libnm. Fixed upstream.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just another question. Am I enable to test the fix on my Ubuntu? Or I have to wait till the fix will pass to the Ubuntu repo?

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with everything updated. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I ran

```
    sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

which pushed me up to 16.04.2, and it solved the problem you describe.

Comment: A little late, but this bug is where I got the solution:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openconnect/+bug/1609700