# Network manager doesn't remember login (username) - 2019

Tags: vpn

This seems to be the exact same problem as this was three years ago:
[Network manager doesn't remember login (username)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835556/network-manager-doesnt-remember-login-username)

But I'm as up to date as I know how to get and I have the same thing.  The password is remembered but I have to re-type the user name each time.  It's really just kind of silly, but it is an annoyance to have to do this four or five times a day when the vpn falls over.

Ubuntu 19.04

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hmmm. Unable to duplicate the problem. On Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10, my Network Manager VPN client properly remembers the username, and properly reconnects.

Comment: Do you know where that information should be stored?  
Maybe there is some permissions problem or something I could look into?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on my 19.10. Where are files stored? I'll look at the permissions.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10.

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10 here.

Comment: Same problem Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround that at least works for me (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, GNOME 3.36.8) [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2105#note_833969) (based on
[this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openconnect/+bug/1609700/comments/64)):

```
nmcli con mod VPNNAME vpn.secrets 'form:main:username=USERNAME','save_passwords=yes'
```

Replace `VPNNAME` and `USERNAME` accordingly. Maybe you also need to add `'form:main:group_list=GROUPNAME'`

Comment: This worked for Rocky Linux 8.4 as well (so likely on RHEL,CentOS and Fedora too).